# How to set a URL (which is a IP address) as redirect URL in google API credentials?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, google-api

I created an API project  (https://code.google.com/apis/console).Under the project I selected the API Access and created an OAUTH2 client ID.In the details I entered my website address containing the IP address(http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/crm/index.php?module=Calendar&view=List),but the validation failed.
Is there any way to set the redirect URL as 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/crm/index.php?module=Calendar&view=List'.Can we change it in the PHP file downloaded for google syncronization.
waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Public IP addresses cannot be used for the OAuth redirect URI:
[Can a public IP address be used as Google OAuth redirect URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238665/can-a-public-ip-address-be-used-as-google-oauth-redirect-uri)

As far as I remember, Google OAuth requires you to set the same value for redirect URI within the PHP codebase. It's located in Config.php

It checks this against the value specified in Google Apps settings, so make sure it's exactly the same.

You should also check out: 
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob or urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:auto (special URIs) and see if you can use them instead of buying a domain.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp