# How to use private IP as a "Authorized JavaScript origin" in Google OAuth client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

I implemented a "Log in with google" in my website using Google OAuth2.
In the Google API console, in the `Authorized JavaScript origins` list I currently have `http://localhost:3000`.

But now I want to test my web app from multiple devices within my LAN, so I serve my app over a public IP that every device in the LAN can access (lets say `192.168.3.121` over port `3000`).

The problem is that i can't use IP addresses in `Authorized JavaScript origins`, Is there a solution to this?
[That's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238665/can-a-public-ip-address-be-used-as-google-oauth-redirect-uri) the only related post I could find about this, I tried using `xip.io` like suggested (`192.168.3.121.xip.io:3000`) But when authenticating with Google I get: `Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.`

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem ?