# Google web client OAuth 2.0 JavaScript origins with private IP or local DNS name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-signin, intranet

I am trying to set up a Login with Google button for a web app of a company intranet.

Is it ok to use a login with Google button for a web app that is **not published on the internet** but is only for an intranet?

Specifically, it possible to set a *local domain name* or a *private IP* as authorized origins for Javascript?

I just found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130541/how-to-use-private-ip-as-a-authorized-javascript-origin-in-google-oauth-client) but without answers...

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238665/can-a-public-ip-address-be-used-as-google-oauth-redirect-uri) suggestions, I also already tried:

- nip.io and sslip.io.
- using a mycustomdomain.com and put in Windows hosts file "127.0.0.1 mycustomdomain.com"
- attach the :80 port to every Javascript Origins

In all these cases I keep receiving a client-side error ["The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abOxq.png) despite, for the last two cases I have [these allowed javascript origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZFsG.png), [this request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It1sB.png) and this in the Windows host file:

```
10.9.1.112 rd.raicam.com
```

Where 10.9.1.112 is just a test server with the webapp loaded to it... just for not use localhost and try to make the login work.

I would be grateful if you could provide me with a suggestion...
I haven't found any official Google clarification on this topic.

Comment: _"I also already tried:"_ - and what specific problems/errors did you run into? Which point of this exactly is causing trouble? Are you not able to store the setting in your app dashboard, are you getting errors on the client side, ...?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified the question by clarifying the error that I am encountering.

Comment: And what origin value actually gets _used_? Can't see that from those screen-shotted messages.

Comment: Ok I just added also the request header... do you mean the Origin value, right?